# Print weeks between a certain daterange

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in my excel sheet that can be reproduced by this function:

```
sub dummy_data

    start_date = Sheets("Blad1").Cells(2, 4) = "20-03-2014"
    end_date = Sheets("Blad1").Cells(3, 4) = 20-04-2014"

End sub
```

Now I would like to create a list of all weeks between these dates. Therefore I did:

```
Sub print_dates

  start_date = Sheets("Blad1").Cells(2, 4)
  end_date = Sheets("Blad1").Cells(3, 4)

  'Get number of weeks
    r = (end_date - start_date) / 7
    r = Round(r)

  new_date = start_date
  counter = 0

  While (new_date < (end_date - 7))

   For i = 1 To r

       counter = counter + 7
       new_date = start_date + counter

  'print date
      Sheets("Blad1").Cells(i, 4).FormulaLocal = new_date
  Next i
Wend

End sub
```

This works a little however but it gives me always one row too much. So if I
enter start_date = 23-3-2013 and end_date 04-04-2013 I get one value after 04-04-2013.

Any thoughts on how I can an overview with only the weeks between a certain range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `For Loop` inside the `While Loop`.

That said, I just tested this code and it worked and is simpler.

```
Sub print_dates()

  start_date = Sheets("Blad1").Cells(2, 4)
  end_date = Sheets("Blad1").Cells(3, 4)

  new_date = start_date

  i = 1

  While (new_date < (end_date - 7))

    new_date = new_date + 7

    'print date
    Sheets("Blad1").Cells(i, 5).FormulaLocal = new_date

    i = i + 1

   Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
Sub print_dates()

start_date = Sheets("Blad1").Cells(2, 4)
end_date = Sheets("Blad1").Cells(3, 4)

'Get number of weeks
r = (end_date - start_date) / 7
r = Round(r)

new_date = start_date
counter = 0
For i = 1 To r
    If new_date + 7 <= end_date Then
        counter = counter + 7
        new_date = start_date + counter

        'print date
        Sheets("Blad1").Cells(i, 5).FormulaLocal = new_date

    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using datediff to determine how many weeks. Just easier. 
[MSDN has a really good datediff function tutorial here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
R = DateDiff("w", startdate, enddate) ' Determine week difference between two dates.
```

Also, I suspect the extra week is being added because the code makes sunday the first day of the week, not monday. So you would have to also take in account the days between currentday and vbsunday. Or just put that in the datediff function like this.

```
R = DateDiff("w", startdate, enddate, vbmonday or whatever current day.)
```